# Qt music player: mini player mode

Tags: c++, qt, audio-player

I'm building a simple music player using Qt. I want to have a mini player mode where a part of the window is hidden. How can this be done? Here is an example:

*Full Mode:*

[image: VLC]

*Mini-Player Mode:*

[image: VLC mini-mode]

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Is it sufficient for you to call hide() on one or more of your widgets, and then resize the window smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical approach in Qt 4 is:

1. Use `QWidget::hide()` and `QWidget::show()` to set the visibility of the individual elements you want to hide.

   If everything is properly structured, it's usually enough to just do this for the high-level elements (e.g. hide an entire toolbar, not the individual buttons; if your video canvas is in a frame, just hide the whole QFrame.)
2. Then, call `QWidget::adjustSize()` on the window itself to tell it to resize.

If the results aren't quite what you expect, the next step is to check on the [size policy rules](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html) of your widgets, spacers, and layouts.